# Cookie "disappears" after a few hours (exp. date is 2 months)

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am currently stuck with  a weird issue which I haven't seen before. Basically, we have a forum (installed in subfolder domain.com/forum, php zend framework), which sets a cookie when the user logs in, the cookie appears in the browser and its expiration date is set for 2k16 (around 2 months). So no problem here BUT  after 2 or 3 hours (not sure about the timewindow), the cookie just disappears ... (or the connection to it). So the user needs to log in again, and it again creates a different cookie with exp date again 2 months.

So I am a bit confused, the forum is running for months without any problems and suddenly those things start to happen. We didn't touch anything on the server/forum etc, it just started. We have a word-press installation in the root, and I am starting to think that a recently installed security plugin could cause this odd behavior. I will probably disable all plugins and see if that fixes it, but since it is a busy site and I need a few hours to verfiy the solution, I am trying first to find the cause.

Any ideas about this ?  I am not sure if something on the Server cleans the cookie automatically (or at least the cookie connection key) and for what to look. Any help is appreciate, thanks!

thx
Ed

Comment: You are saying "an cookie". Are you by any chance talking about the session cookie? The sessions could expire for a bunch of other reasons - it also would explain why the user is logged out, that's why I'm asking

Comment: No (at least i don't think so) it's a real cookie which is stored on the users PC.  To be clear, I can close the browser x times within 2-3h and I still be logged in.  I assume a session cookie would disappear as soon I close the browser?

Comment: No, the session is also maintained by a cookie so it doesn't close when you exit the browser. But check your borwser's cookies settings.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. The cookie doesnt have any size and it has a Content Field with some kind of Key. That could mean its a session cookie?

Comment: Yes, it "could" mean that. Although I am not sure what you mean by it does not have any size. The size is normally the size of the content that is stored therein. In this case, the Key (if it is a session cookie, most probably the Session-ID). Anyways, it seems like you could use some professional technical assistance, which I would recommend you to get somewhere where you feel comfortable with :)